# Why isn't jQuery closest working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a small system that uses collapsable blocks - for this I am have a css class that toggles on or off depending on the jQuery dependancy.

The code I am using is:

```
$("#click_me").on("click", function () {
    $("#clicked_action").toggleClass("show");
});
```

And this works, but is not what is needed. What is need is:

```
$(".collapse-header").on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest(".collapse-body").toggleClass("show");
});
```

But this does not work.

I am not getting any console errors, so any help is apprecated

**EDIT** HTML value:

```
<div class="collapse-header" id="click_me">
    <span class="float-left">Click me</span>
    <span class="float-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
    <hr class="hr" />
</div>
<div class="collapse-body" id="clicked_action">
    I'm collapsed
</div>
```

Comment: where is the html structure?

Comment: I think you need something like `$(this).parent().find(".collapse-body")`

Comment: @ps2goat, added the html

Comment: The problem is that $(this).closest() only finds ancestors, not siblings or the current element.

Comment: @GG., that worked, care to add as answer and I'll accept ASAP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for

```
$(this).parent().find(".collapse-body")
```

---

**About [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest)**

`$(element).closest(selector)` is to find the first element which matches selector in traversing up through element's ancestors.

In your case, your elements are at the same level ("siblings") so `.closest` doesn't work.